# A SELECT statement as a subquery in an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

Will the following query insert as many rows as there are rows in the result-set of the subquery? If not, how can I make insert n rows where n is the number of rows in the result set of the subquery?

```
INSERT INTO A (x, y)
VALUES (@x, SELECT B.z FROM B)

@x=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It'd only ever insert 1 row at most. If you wanted to insert multiple rows, you'd need to something like

```
INSERT INTO A (x,y) SELECT @X, B.z FROM b
```

Note that there's no `values` clause, and the @x has been integrated into the `SELECT` query

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to get all the values, you could amend it to:

```
INSERT INTO A (x, y) 
SELECT @x, B.z 
FROM B
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the VALUES clause. Your query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO A (x, y) SELECT @X, B.z FROM B
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way.

```
INSERT INTO A
    (x, y)
    SELECT @x, B.z
        FROM B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @X int = 5

INSERT INTO A
(
    x,
    y
)
SELECT    
    @X,
    B.Z
FROM B
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to work. You are making the same mistake as to using an Aggregate function on a multiple row query